# Check if user has access to SharePoint Online site

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have the code below:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(URL))
{
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);

    Web web = context.Web;
    context.Load(web.Lists, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title, list => list.Id));
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    List SupportList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Support");

    ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
    ListItem newItem = SupportList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

    foreach (var selector in f.rtxt_select.Text.Split(','))
    {
        var s = selector.Split('=');
        newItem[s[0].Trim()] = m.GetType().GetProperty(s[1].Trim()).GetValue(m, null);
    }

    newItem.Update();

    context.ExecuteQuery();
    f.txtMessage.AppendText("Message has been added to Sharepoint List \n ");
    f.lbl_successCount.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(f.lbl_successCount.Text) + 1).ToString();
}
```

Everything works just fine if the username and password is correct. But Is there is a way i can validate if the user has access to the site(`SharePoint Online`)?

Comment: if the user don't have access the execute query will return access denied

Answer (score 0):

Check [Web.GetUserEffectivePermissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getusereffectivepermissions.aspx) method.